# IQKeyboardManager – wrong keyboard layout when split view is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I am experiencing a strange issue using [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) when keyboard split mode is enabled. 
 Keyboard's background isn't transparent:

[image]

But keyboard's background is transparent when IQKeyboardManager is not used:

[image]

**EDIT** How to reproduce:

```
//AppDelegate.swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ...
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    ...
}

//ViewController.swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    textField.keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 140 // or any constant
    ...
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) library's maintainer ([answer](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1388)). 
Keyboard's background is fully transparent if you disable `autoToolbar`:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
```